# jetty websockets connection closing connection and sending messages are thread safe?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jetty, websocket

I've started adding to my application a small websocket server based on jetty.

However I'm interested since I didn't find anywhere in the documentation if the sendMessage and disconnect methods are called asynchronous or synchronous?

In case the methods are asynchronous what is the callback method??

here is the link with the documentation: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocket.Connection.html#sendMessage%28java.lang.String%29

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `sendMessage()` method is asynchronous.

The callback methods can be found in the following interfaces [WebSocket.OnBinaryMessage](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocket.OnBinaryMessage.html) and [WebSocket.OnTextMessage](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocket.OnTextMessage.html), with the `onMessage()` method.

I think that you have to handle the request/response protocol by hand.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've already implemented a class based on WebSocket.OnTextMessage but the onMessage method is called only when receiving messages and not when I send it. How about the disconnect method? is this also asynchronous?

Comment: I don't understanding what you're trying to achieve. What is your goal when you send a message ?

Comment: let's suppose I have a code doSomething(); sendMessage(); doSomethingElse(); I want to be sure that doSomethingElse() is called only after the message was sent

Comment: Then do the doSomethingElse() in your callback, with an id or something sent with the sendMessage() and retrieved in your doSomethingElse()

Answer (score 0):

The title of your post asked if the methods are thread safe, but in the body you're asking if they are synchronous - those are separate questions.

I only looked at sendMessage() and it seems like the addFrame() calls (they do the actual writing to the buffers) are thread safe / synchronized.

Still not sure if they are synchronous though.